# Wrong general total in a Power BI Matrix

Tags: powerbi, measure

I want to calculate the Herfindalh-Hirschmann Index (sum of market shares at square) bu publisher. In Power BI, i have 2 measures, the market share and the suare of market share for each publisher. My calculations are good but the general total is false for the square of market share.

My DAX code is this for the Market Share (correct calculation & total) :
`Market Share = VAR Volume =
SUM('Sales - Global'[Sales])

VAR AllVolume =
CALCULATE(SUM('Sales - Global'[Sales]), ALL('Publisher'))

RETURN
DIVIDE(Volume, AllVolume)`

My DAX code is this for the Squared Market Share. I ant to conserve the (*100) to better interprete the result. Calculations are good but the general total is incorrect. :

```
Market Share Square = 
VAR Volume = SUM('Sales - Global'[Sales])
VAR AllVolume = CALCULATE(SUM('Sales - Global'[Sales]), ALL('Publisher'[Publisher]))
VAR MarketShare = DIVIDE(Volume, AllVolume)*100
RETURN
    MarketShare * MarketShare
```

[image: Table]

Answer (score 0):

For the grand total the measure is evaluated without a single Publisher in the filter context.  so

VAR Volume = SUM('Sales - Global'[Sales])

and

VAR AllVolume = CALCULATE(SUM('Sales - Global'[Sales]), ALL('Publisher'[Publisher]))

are the same.

If you want to run a calculation for *each* publisher and add them up use [SUMX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/sumx-function-dax).

What you're expecting is a behavior called "visual calculations", which Power BI doesn't yet support.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/release-plan/2023wave2/power-bi/visual-calculations

Comment: What is the good code to fix this issue ?